# Google Charts - Trying to add links or any form of custom html in popup

Tags: javascript, html, charts, hyperlink

Is there any way to have links in any part or a google chart?
Or embeded html?

I would idealy like to format the pop-up with my own html.
some(3) and other(4) should be links.

[image: Links needed in this pop-up]

This is the closest I could get to what I would need [Dynamic icons](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html).

By reading on the net I am starting to think that my best option would be to not display google's popup and display a custom div instead.

Edit 1:
Google themselfes have a clickable link "Create new annotation" on their google analytics reports, so anything like that would be great.

[image]

Comment: Could you try to see the source code in the Google Analytics report and then learn how they do it from that? Unfortunately, I don't have access to Google Analytics myself... Sorry.

Comment: Last time I checked, google analytics was flash-powered so it wasn't near impossible to analyze their code. Whatever the case, in order to help you, plz post the code that lead to that tooltip/popup so that we may help you modify it.

Comment: I think your best option is to, as you say, display your own div with your HTML in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the Annotated Time Line from Google Visualizations. Take a look at the first configuration option. :)

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html#Configuration_Options